# Taking duplicate lines and squeezing them into 1 row on SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to write a stored procedure in SQL Server that will eliminate some logic in my C# program. What I'm doing right now is the query is in a view. Then I'm making a list with the view.

```
List<MyView> listOrdered = new List<MyView>();
```

Here's where it gets hairy. The query returns rows that are duplicates. I don't want to delete the duplicate rows I want to combine them into 1 row. The rows are identical except for 1 column.

Example:

```
UID     Name     Age    Child
1       John     50     Sally
1       John     50     Steve
2       Joseph   42     Timmy
2       Joseph   42     Billy
```

So what I'm doing in C# is writing logic that says: (pseudo code)

```
foreach(item in list)
{
      if (UID != UIDCurrent)
      { 
          Build Row
          AppendRow to list
      }
      else
      {
          Append Child Column to Current Child Column
       }
}
```

Basically it gives me:

```
UID     Name     Age   Children
1       John     50    Sally, Steve
```

But instead of doing this logic in C# I would like to do this a stored procedure. So how I can I get SQL Server to combine the children column for each row instead of multiple rows.

If you need anything else to help you help me I will respond.

Oh guys believe me I don't want to do it this way either. The Database I'm using is huge and complex and doing this with C# was sensible and works but I've been asked to turn my function that does this in C# into a stored procedure. I just want to see if this is even possible.

Comment: Honestly. Do it in your code. That is where that type of logic belongs. Note: The code will get cleaner if you normalize your database to at least 3NF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if you want to do this in the database, though you should think about doing it in the front-end.

```
SELECT  UID,    
    Name, 
    Age,
    STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' + Child AS [text()]
            FROM parentChildren b
            WHERE a.UID = b.UID
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') [ChildConcat]
FROM parentChildren a
```

Answer (score 4):

This demonstrates a poor table design. Fix it at the root and then you don't have this silly logic in either your db or C# code.

instead of

```
people(UID, Name, Age, Child)
```

try

```
people(UID, Name, DateOfBirth)  
children(Parent references people.UID, child references people.UID)
```

You can leave age instead of moving to date of birth but it's really a much better idea to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is 100%, without a doubt something to be handled in your application code, **NOT in the database!**

SQL performs fairly poorly in string manipulation operations, especially compared to iterative languages like `C#`.  You want your database to pass you the actual DATA, and then how you display that to be handled in the application layer.

Any attempt to solve this in SQL will be slower and harder to maintain than a version in your application code.